# Sub rows in table aligned to to main table columns

Tags: html, css, datatable, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm using vuetify's data table. I want to use the expanded slot to show more rows in the table.
For example:
[image]
The blue colored rows are sub rows of `January 2nd`, sells and revenue sums up.

It seems the `expanded-item` slot for `v-data-table` is inside `<tr>` tag, that's why the official documentation uses `<td>` in it.
Assuming my item looks like:

```
{
  month: 'January',
  day: 2,
  sells: 29,
  revenue: 428,
  byHour: [
    {hour: 7, sells: 3, revenue: 33},
    ...
  ]
}
```

If I use the slot like that:

```
<template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
  <td></td>
  <td>item.byHour[0].hour</td>
  <td>item.byHour[0].sells</td>
  <td>item.byHour[0].revenue</td>
</template>
```

It looks fine. The content of the sub rows is aligned with the columns of the main table,
But I want to use `v-for`, I tried to wrap the code above in `<tr>` or `<table>` but it doesn't use the whole slot width or the columns of the sub rows are not aligns with the main row and table.

how can I achieve my goal?

Thanks.